# How to get particular field data from json

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have get Json data from API. please tell me how to call API and print particular field data. my API is

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=52385ff92cb9105e52d86c4786293ce8&page=1

Answer (score 0):

```
$url="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=52385ff92cb9105e52d86c4786293ce8&page=1";
```

**Using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)**

```
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump json data
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

**Using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)**

```
$result = file_get_contents($url);
// Will dump json data
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using code below?

```
$url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=52385ff92cb9105e52d86c4786293ce8&page=1";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ajax post you can call the url to get josn Data as below. dowload latest jquery from jquery.com.

You can use http://jsonlint.com/ website to validate and format your json data,  so that you understand the structure of json data easily.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=52385ff92cb9105e52d86c4786293ce8&page=1',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(resp)
    {
       var jsonObj=$.parseJSON(resp); //converting json string to jsonobject
        var results=jsonObj.results; //to gest result array from json code
        var page_number=jsonObj.page; // to get page number from json data

     }
})
```